# Naming the new instances of a class with numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to create new instances of a class and I would like to name them as such

vektor1
vektor2
vektor3 and so forth. As a numerating source I want to use the value of the i which belongs to the for loop. Here is the for loop I am using for this

```
for(int i=0; i<5;i++){
        System.out.println ("Bitte geben sie die erste Koordinat der "+(i+1)+". Vektor ein");
        double k1=scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Bitte geben sie die zweite Koordinat der "+(i+1)+". Vektor ein");
        double k2=scan.nextDouble();

        System.out.println ("Bitte geben sie die dritte Koordinat der "+(i+1)+". Vektor ein");
        double k3=scan.nextDouble();

        vektor.add(new Vektor3Dcomparable(k1,k2,k3));
    }
```

Here I would like to name the instances of the class, before adding it to the ArrayList. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Vektor3Dcomparable` override `Object.toString()` to return your desired object name.

```
@Override public String toString() { 
  return "Mein 3D Vektor Nummer " + ind; 
}
```

If you want to assign a specific name, you'll have to pass that name (or index number, in your case) to the constructor, along with your `k1, k2, k3`.

```
  final double[] k = new double[3];
  for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      System.out.println ("Bitte geben sie die " + 
          (j == 1? "ers" : j == 2? "zwei" : "drit") +
          "te Koordinat der "+(i+1)+". Vektor ein");
      k[j] = scan.nextDouble();
    }
    vektor.add(new Vektor3Dcomparable(k[0], k[1], k[2], i));
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to distinguish between *variables* and *objects*. Variables have names - objects typically don't. `double` values certainly don't, and unless your `Vektor3Dcomparable` has a particular name, there's nothing to do here.

Assuming `vector` is empty beforehand, you're already *sort of* associating the reference with the counter - in that afterwards you could use:

```
Vektor3Dcomparable vektor = vektor.get(2);
```

for example. If you can be clearer about what you want to do with these "names" we may be able to help more.

Comment: Actually what I want to do is, giving names to the objects. when I create a new instance of the class Vektor3Dcomparable java gives it a random name, like Hue2.Vektor3Dcomparable@32c8f6f8. I want to give them names as I create them in the for loop like vektor1, vektor2 ...

Comment: @oderebek: Then you'll need to add a string field to the class, and pass the name in the constructor.